# Bootstrap 3 exclude screen-lg

Tags: html, css, media-queries, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi.

I have to exclude the large breakpoint from Bootstrap 3 and I don't know from where to start. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set

```
/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
   width:1024px;     /* Set desired container width here */ 
   }
 }
```

and then use `col-` classes as usual.

Comment: So overwriting is the only possible solution?

Comment: yes, overriding is the only solution to get what you expected since bootstrap 3 uses mediaqueries to stack and align `col`s.